# Django reverse query by the last created object

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-queryset

I have two models:

```
class SomeActivity(models.Model):
    name = models.ChartField(max_length=100)

class SomeStatus(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    status = models.IntegerField(choises=STATUS_CHOISES)
    some_activity = models.ForeignKey(SomeActivity, related_name='statuses')
```

The last created status for the activity is the current one. To get it I use this code:

```
try:
    last_status = some_activity.statuses.latest('id')
except:
    last_status = None
```

But the problem is when I want to make a query that returns all `Activities` that have a `last_status` matching `status__in=[1, 2]`.

Comment: What's the list [1,2]?

Comment: status from the SomeStatus object. I  edit the question to be more clear.

Answer (score 2):

This solution is a little twisted, but I think it will work:

```
from django.db.models import Max

max_status_ids = SomeActivity.objects.filter(statuses__isnull=False).annotate(
              last_status_id=Max('statuses__id')
              ).values_list('last_status_id', flat=True)
status_satisfied_ids = SomeStatus.objects.filter(id__in=list(max_status_ids),
              status__in=[1, 2]).values_list('id', flat=True)
activities = SomeActivity.objects.filter(statuses__id__in=list(
              status_satisfied_ids))
```

I hope there is a better solution.

---

*update*

Try

```
max_status_ids = SomeActivity.objects.annotate(last_status_id=Max('statuses')
                                    ).values('last_status_id')
activities = SomeActivity.objects.filter(statuses__in=max_status_ids,
                                         statuses__status__in=(1,2))
```

1. Django automatically generates sub-query when `qs`, `qs.values()` or `qs.values_list()` is used after `__in` lookup. Thus there is no need to wrap the querysets w/ `list()` (which also introduces unnecessary evaluation and thus unnecessary intermediate SQLs) or to write `flat=True` inside `qs.values_list()`
2. `statuses__id__in` lookup inside `activities` already introduces a table join, thus it's bette to move `status__in` from `status_satisfied_ids` into `activities` to take advantage of the join. Or else, `status_satisfied_ids` would introduce extra select.

Or you could use [Window functions of PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/tutorial-window.html) to filter by ranked position directly.

Comment: @okm I read the doc of 1.4, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#in the end of this section, django recommend split the queries using mysql, I do not know it will be better in pg.

Comment: I don't know what level of performance the MySQL would achieve, they say it's bad. Normally Postgres works fine on this kind of job -- for not-that-large tables. For large tables, `in` subquery is still slower than [self-join](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/) or window function. Second, large `in` clause doesn't perform well, neither [in MySQL](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/06/28/why-large-in-clauses-are-problematic/) or Postgres.

Comment: Just test in Postgres w/ two tables having 100k rows. 'in' clause is slowest: whole => 3200ms, limit 10 => 800ms, offset 50000 limit 10 => 2950ms; self-join: whole => 650ms, limit 10 => 0.3ms, offset 50000 limit 10 => 620ms; window function: whole => 510ms, limit 10 => 310ms, offset 50000 limit 10 => 440ms. We can see none of the above methods performance quite well in real time for large tables, we should add cache or de-normalized field if the operation is frequent.