# How to query most recent record across multiple tables in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have two models that look like this:

```
class Node(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Activation(models.Model):
    node = models.ForeignKey(Node, null=False)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(default=datetimeM.datetime.now)
```

The activation table stores whether a given node is "active" or not.  So to figure out whether a node is active, one needs to get the latest activation record for that node.

I'm trying to figure out how to write a django query that returns all active nodes.

Here is some example data

```
Node Table
  id  |   name
--------------------
   0  |  andrew
   1  |   bill
   2  |   bob

Activation Table
  id  | nodeId | active | datetime
--------------------
   0  |   0    |  false | 01-01-2013:00:01:02
   1  |   0    |   true | 01-02-2013:00:01:02
   2  |   0    |  false | 01-03-2013:00:01:02
   3  |   1    |  false | 01-04-2013:00:01:02
   4  |   0    |   true | 01-05-2013:00:01:02
   5  |   1    |   true | 01-06-2013:00:01:02
   6  |   2    |  false | 01-07-2013:00:01:02
```

So the query would need to return [node0, node1]

Answer (score 0):

```
class Node(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Activation(models.Model):
   node = models.ForeignKey(Node, null=False, related_name='activations')
   active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   datetime = models.DateTimeField(default=datetimeM.datetime.now)

   #latest activation record for that node:
   try:
      latest_activation = node.activations.latest('id')
   except:
      latest_activation = None

   # Return all active notes:
    all_active_notes = Node.objects.filter(activations__active=True)
```

Updated:
Check this question what I posted yestarday:
[Django reverse query by the last created object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14922508/django-reverse-query-by-the-last-created-object)
maybe this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @UnLiMiTeD but I'm not sure I understand.  `all_active_notes` will just be a list of nodes that have at some point been active.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I've added some example data and an expected answer.  I had a look at the post you suggested but I don't think it helps me.